# AsyncStorage getItem and setItem doesn't work in Android device

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am trying to store the values of current date in milliseconds in AsyncStorage setItem and retrieve it by using getItem when the state of app changes. I'm using AppState listeners for changing state and comparing the values. This works fine when i run it on ios simulators but doesn't work when i run on an android device. Can anyone help me out?

```
    StoreDate = async () => {

        console.log("Date",new Date().getTime().toString());
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('date', new Date().getTime().toString());
      };

      retrieveDate = async () => 
      {
        try{
        let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('date')
         var Intvalue = parseInt(value,10); // value of newDate().getTime() as Integer
         console.log("Intvalue",Intvalue);
        console.log("value",value);
        Alert.alert(value);
        return value;
    }
          catch(error){
            Alert.alert(error);
          }
      };

    _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => 
         if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive/) && nextAppState === 'background') {

          let getDateTime = this.StoreDate().then((filter) => {
            console.log("filter",filter);
            console.log("getDateTime",getDateTime);
          });
      }
  else if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {

let currentDate = new Date().getTime();   
          let currentDateTimeStamp =   Math.floor(currentDate / 1000);

           console.log("currentDate",currentDate);
           console.log("currentDateTimeStamp",currentDateTimeStamp);




          let storedTime = this.retrieveDate().then((filter)=>  {

            console.log("filter",filter);
            console.log("storedTime",storedTime);

            var Intfilter = parseInt(filter,10);
            console.log("Intfilter",Intfilter);


            var IntfilterSeconds = Math.floor(Intfilter / 1000);
            console.log("IntfilterSeconds",IntfilterSeconds);

             var timeDiff = currentDateTimeStamp - IntfilterSeconds;
            console.log("timeDiff",timeDiff)



            if(timeDiff > 300){
              ** DO Something ** 

              })



             }
            else{
          **   Do Something **
              })

           }

           });

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround for this problem. 
I found out that this was not a problem with AsyncStorage but the AppState. 
There are mainly two appstate in android: Active and Background.
Handling the appState when the app is in background to match(active|background) && nextAppState='background' did solve the problem for me.